# MySQL seems to be very slow for updates

Tags: mysql

MySQL seems to be very slow for updates.
A simple update statement is taking more time than MS SQL for same update call.

Ex:

```
UPDATE ValuesTbl SET value1 = @value1,
                     value2 = @value2
    WHERE co_id = @co_id
      AND sel_date = @sel_date
```

I have changed some config settings as below

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2

innodb_buffer_pool_size=10G

innodb_log_file_size=2G

log-bin="foo-bin"

skip-log-bin
```

This is the create table query

```
CREATE TABLE `valuestbl` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sel_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `co_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value1` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `value2` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21621889 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

MySQL version: 8.0 on Windows

The update query takes longer time to update when compared to MS SQL, anything else I need to do to make it faster?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Does the table you are using contain any indices?

Comment: Have tried changing the default config settings of ini file, did not help.
There are no indices, the ValuesTbl tables has a PK, not using for anything. the id column is a Primary key from another table, the sel_date is a date field and 2 decimal columns

Comment: @MohdSaleemNavalur Can we see `show create table ValuesTbl` please?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There are no indices, the ValuesTbl tables has a PK, not using for anything. the id column is a Primary key from another table, the sel_date is a date field and 2 decimal columns

If there are no indexes on `ValuesTbl` then the update has to scan the entire table which will be slow if the table is large. No amount of server tuning will fix this.

> A simple update statement is taking more time than MS SQL for same update call.

The MS SQL server probably has an index on either `co_id` or `sel_date`. Or it has fewer rows in the table.

You need to add indexes, like the index of a book, so the database doesn't have to search the whole table. At minimum an index on `co_id` will vastly help performance. If there are many columns with different `sel_date` per ID, a compound index on `(co_id, sel_date)` would help further.

See [Use The Index, Luke](https://use-the-index-luke.com/) for an extensive tutorial on indexes.

Comment: Add the composite index; don't bother with either single-column index.

Comment: After a created an index with 2 columns co_id and sel_date. The performance zoomed up. Thanks all for the help.